# Where did Gamora find the Map to the Soul Stone?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

Where did Gamora find the Map to the Soul Stone in *Avengers: Infinity War*? On her planet or on Titan or elsewhere? At that point does she travel to Vormir without Thanos' knowledge? How does she know where on the planet Vormir to take Thanos when they visit together if she only assumes the map she found is true? Did she previously meet Red Skull? How was she certain the stone was there otherwise?

Comment: It's impossible that she had met the Red Skull. If she had gone to the planet alone, Red Skull would instruct her that she should come back with someone she loves in order to sacrifice them and reach the stone. But Gamora got surprised when she found out the sacrifice requirement when she went to Vormir with Thanos.

Answer (score 4):

## We don't know!

There is no explanation given as to how Gamora locates the map or the location of the Soul Stone, she just announces that she *does* know.

The locations of the various stones is purely an MCU construct, there is no equivalent in the comics which have a somewhat different structure than the movies.